# Default to All and hide retweets on Twitter search results

Tags: twitter, search

How can I default the sort of Twitter search results to show "All" instead of "Top" and have it exclude retweets?

On Twitter I don't follow anyone or post anything, I just use it to search to get timely news.

When I search, by default I am shown "Top" results, which are nearly always irrelevant because they are old.  I can click on the "All" link to have them sorted by time, but this is getting annoying.  Can I default to showing "All" instead of "Top"?

It also shows the same result over and over again.  It says "retweeted by **_**" on it each time.  I assume this means that different users shared the original post.  I don't need to see this post more than once as it's just the same information over and over again - is there a way to also not show these "retweets" in my search results?

Comment: Blocking: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17475/what-happens-when-i-block-someone-on-twitter

Comment: In future, don't lump multiple questions in one post

Answer (score 1):

To go directly to the "All" tab, you can create the search URL yourself like so:

`https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=stackexchange&src=typd`

Where `stackexchange` is your search query and `f=realtime` is the equivalent of selecting the "All" tab.

---

You can try adding `exclude:retweets` to your search query but I'm not 100% sure how that works as it seems to not include tweets that have been retweeted. Another strategy is to simply do "-RT" in your search query to weed out some retweets.